# How to use swipe guesture on two views in swift

Tags: swift

When I swap from right to left anywhere on the simulator it is swapping but I want to swap only on the View of green.
    I have Tried this..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var red: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var green: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var sswipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     Selector("handleSwipes:"))
        sswipe.direction = .Left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(sswipe)

        var srwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
        srwipe.direction = .Right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(srwipe)

}

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.direction == .Left) {
        var labelPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x - 100.0, self.view.frame.origin.y)
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(labelPosition.x , labelPosition.y , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
    }
    if(sender.direction == .Right) {
        var labelPosition = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + 100.0, self.view.frame.origin.y)
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(labelPosition.x , labelPosition.y , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add youy gesture to green. green.addGestureRecognizer(srwipe)

Comment: Thanks. It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your gesture to the main view, you need to add it to the desired view in your case its green so it should be

```
green.addGestureRecognizer(sswipe)
```

Comment: I have two views one is green and one is red. but red is appeared with black background, I want with white same as green view coming.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first declare swipe gesture in viewdidload

```
 let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainNotificationVC.swipeLeft))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    ViewGreen.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainNotificationVC.swipeRight))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    viewRed.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

than after

```
 func swipeLeft() {

    //animation
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    self.ViewGreen.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
    // add your code
}
func swipeRight() {

    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    self.viewRed.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
}
```